# Which one is correct "alle diese Rezepte" or "all diese Rezepte"?

Tags: grammar

How do I say *"all the food"* in German?

1. Ich möchte all diese Rezepte in diesem Kochbuch kochen.
2. Ich möchte alle diese Rezepte in diesem Kochbuch kochen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You managed to come up with a bit funny sentences. Mind you that "Rezeptsuppe" or "Geröstete Rezepte an Sahnesoße" are not likely what you want do cook.

Say the following:

> Ich möchte alle Rezepte ausprobieren.
>
> Ich möchte alle Speisen/Gerichte nach Rezepten dieses Kochbuchs kochen/zubereiten.

Comment: Nevertheless we would understand what @DerPolyglott33 means. For colloquial german I'd say 'Ich kann dieses Rezept kochen/zubereiten' is ok.
Furthermore: It doesn't matter if you say 'all diese Rezepte' oder 'alle diese Rezepte' - we use both.